# Visual Studio Code on Mac OSX for python and C++

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code

When I try to run a python file in VS Code I get the error `Tasks are only available in a workspace folder.`

What am I supposed to have in my `settings.json` file for python? Also, can someone can just explain how VSC works by altering these `.json` files?

Answer (score 0):

VS Code only supports Build Tasks if you have opened a folder in VS Code. To open a folder in VS Code, you can go to `File -> Open Folder`.

Then, VS Code knows where you are working, and can create a `.vscode/tasks.json` file in that folder, specific to the folder you opened, which VS Code calls a "workspace".

Answer (score 0):

ANSWERED: figure out where python is located in your computer. In terminal type `which python3` (for python 3)
which for me returns `/usr/local/bin/python3`

In Visual Studio Code open Command Palette and type "Preferences:Configure Language Specific Settings", then choose "python"

add `"python.pythonPath":"/usr/local/bin/python3"` or for you `python.pythonPath":"Directory_to_python_that_terminal_returned"`to the .json file

Run your python files!~!~!~!~!